# Getting error in hive when trying to run select count(*) query from table

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am using hadoop-2.10.0 with hive installed on top of it. i am able to create tables, alter table and perform select * query on it, but when i'm trying to select count(*) query for table i'm getting job failure error. On checking furthur logs i'm getting

```
Application application_1587095329681_0006 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1587095329681_0006_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-04-17 11:20:46.294]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1587095329681_0006_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
"Setting up env variables"
"Setting up job resources"
[2020-04-17 11:20:46.295]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
[2020-04-17 11:20:46.296]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://Watson:8088/cluster/app/application_1587095329681_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application
```

looked like permission error so i gave chmod 755 to /user/hive/warehouse. but still getting the same issue.

- OS: windows 7
- Hadoop version: 2.10.0
- Hive version: 2.1.0

Comment: Are you running as administrator? If not, try that.

Comment: Yes I'm running the commands as admintrator

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Steps

1. Open Command Prompt in admin mode navigate to hadoop sbin directory
2. Open start-dfs.cmd
3. Open start-yarn.cmd
4. Run your Script

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered a similar issue and it looks like using

select count(*) requires alter permission for the table

select count(1) only requires read permission

PS. the 1 is irrelevant, you can use 2, or 50, 1000000000, or 'hahahaha'

I also don't know WHY this is happening, currently researching the WHY.